# How do I solve psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column reference "account_analytic_id" is ambiguous in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-12

I am trying to move a module from odoo 8 to odoo 12 and I get this error when trying to install an odoo 8 module in an odoo 12 environment.

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column reference "account_analytic_id" is ambiguous
LINE 18: ..., sub.product_id, sub.partner_id, sub.country_id, sub.accoun...
```

This is the code block from which I suspect the error is coming from

```py
class AccountInvoiceReport(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice.report'

    cost_center_id = fields.Many2one(
        'account.cost.center',
        string='Cost Center',
        readonly=True
    )
    account_analytic_id = fields.Many2one(
        'account.analytic.account',
        string='Analytic Account',
        readonly=True
    )

    def _select(self):
        return super(AccountInvoiceReport, self)._select() + \
            ", sub.cost_center_id as cost_center_id, " + \
            "sub.account_analytic_id as account_analytic_id"

    def _sub_select(self):
        return super(AccountInvoiceReport, self)._sub_select() + \
            ", ail.cost_center_id as cost_center_id, " + \
            "ail.account_analytic_id as account_analytic_id"

    def _group_by(self):
        return super(AccountInvoiceReport, self)._group_by() + \
            ", ail.cost_center_id, " + \
            "ail.account_analytic_id"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you've tagged Odoo version 8 and version 12?

Comment: yeah to give it more audience to developers experienced with both versions I presume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the query parts with `account_analytic_id`, because it's already in the `account.invoice.report` of Odoo 12.

Can be seen [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/1c3d51283edfbe9b7339690515189f2b06cc82dc/addons/account/report/account_invoice_report.py)